# facebook post to wall with big picture

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post to facebook wall by my app
but something confuse me

this is my post 
[image]

and i hope the picture can as big as below one
[image]

here is my code

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"message":@"www.apple.com.tw this is message",
                             @"link":@"www.yahoo.com.tw",
                             @"caption":@"link_caption",
                             @"description":@"dff",
                             @"name":@"erh",
                             @"picture":@"http://cdn.wall88.com/51a4f786c959d55670.jpg"

                             };

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"post"];

    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error){

        if (!error)
        {
            NSLog(@"sdg");
        }
    }];
```

and if i delete@"link":@"www.yahoo.com.tw"

the picture is what i want
but the link is car picture's link 
[image]

car picture's size is 1920*1080

is i missing something?

can i control the picture size?

thanks in advance

======anser edit=====

image size 1200 * 630 is useful

but at beginning you post

facebook seem to need some time to detect image size,so it appear as a square image

press F5 more times, it will become big image

Comment: your coding fine , sometimes Facebook changed like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the suggestions from Facebook for image sizes:

> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on
> high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that
> are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.
>
> You should use a 1.91:1 image ratio, such as 600 x 314 px.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

...that´s all you can do, Facebook decides about how it will look like, depending on many factors - for example, how many users liked stuff on that domain (i guess).

Comment: i had seen that article, but my picture is 1920*1080, i don't think this is a problem. so, you think i can't control picture size?

Comment: you can only use an image that fits to the specifications, you can´t control it in any other way, facebook will decide how it will look like.

Comment: make sure it´s 1.91:1, i´ve added the quote to my answer